# how to mask email and phone number with regular expression with fixed length substitution

Tags: c#, .net, regex, email, substitution

I am writing regEx for masking Email address and Phone number in Azure B2C Claims

My requirement is as follows,

For Email address, I need to display first two characters of the email unmasked and fixed 5 * (masked) irrespective of length remaining characters and unmasked "@domain.com"
Expected Result (for example):

testaccount@gmail.com ==> te*****@gmail.com

test@gmail.com ==>te*****@gmail.com

My regular expression is currently display first two characters and replacing remaining characters with *

RegEx: https://regex101.com/r/3xL2ht/1

For Mobile:

I need to display seven asterisk as masked characters irrespective of number digits. last 4 digits should be unmasked.

Expected Result (for example):

+91-1234567890  ==> *******7890

919012345678 ==> *******5678

Current configuration is showing last 4 digits correctly, but preceding digits are replaced by * , if I have 12 digit, it shows eight asterisk and las 4 digit.

Current regEx : https://regex101.com/r/56DpA6/1

Please help me in sorting this out!

Thank you!!

Comment: For phone-numbers you should use `libphonenumber` instead of trying to handle that yourself.

Comment: Try `Regex.Replace(text, @"(?<=.{2})[^@]+(?=@)", "*****")`

Comment: For the second problem, try `Regex.Replace(text, @"[+0-9]+(?=[0-9]{4}$)", "*****")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your mail problem:

replace `([^@]{1,2})[^@]*(.+)` with `$1.....$2`

- search for the two first letters (not '@') and capture them
- search for the rest in front of '@' (and forget it)
- capture the rest (beginning at '@')

[EDIT] I think your other question can be solved very similar. Capture the last digits and concat them to your new (asterisk) string.